# Nginx rules for subdomain multisite install (Bedrock)

Tags: multisite, htaccess, nginx

I'm trying to move an existing Bedrock based multisite instance to nginx and am having difficulty getting a set of nginx rules to mimic the original .htaccess. Bedrock places the crux of the files in a wp/ subdirectory, but the urls still need to be accessible from the root domain.

The .htaccess is here as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I need these at least as nginx conf rules or preferably nginx vhost rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ last;
rewrite ^/(wp-.*.php)$ /wp/$1 last;
rewrite ^/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wp/$1 last;
```

These are the equivalent rewrite rules that you need. Note, when you use this rewrite, you no longer have to set the site_url as /wp

I need to finish up some testing but will update here with the results.

Comment: true true true true! actually you can even see these rules in trelis nginx role: https://github.com/roots/trellis/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/wordpress_multisite_subdirectories.conf.j2

Answer (score 2):

Ok some wise guy deleted my last post.

The answer, which the above member (@etc) gave to me on another forum, and is working quite fine, is as follows:

```
# Rewrites for Bedrock Multi-Site Subdomain Setup
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ last;
rewrite ^/(wp-.*.php)$ /wp/$1 last;
rewrite ^/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wp/$1 last;
```

He revised his answer but did not post it back here. I simply wanted to update it as I ran across this thread as well.

Comment: https://github.com/roots/trellis/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/wordpress_multisite_subdirectories.conf.j2 you can check working version here. endorsed by bedrock creators

Comment: ^^ Those aren't the same rules.

Comment: and not working anymore...